# Cloning element only once, from one sortable list to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two sortable ul-lists.
I want to be able to clone/copy an element from the first list to the second.
An element has to be unique in each list.
When user tries to clone an element a second time, the action should be cancelled and user alerted of the limitation.

I have been experimenting with Sortable, Draggable and Droppable for quite a while now to no avail. This is how far I'm getting: http://jsfiddle.net/wYSZ8/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="demo">
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li id="one" class="default">Item 1</li>
    <li id="two" class="default">Item 2</li>
    <li id="three" class="default">Item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li id="four" class="default">Item a</li>
    <li id="five" class="default">Item b</li>
    <li id="six" class="default">Item c</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#sortable1').sortable();
$('#sortable2').sortable();
```

Comment: What do you plan to do about the duplicate id's when you create a clone? What have you tried?

Comment: Draggable removes the ID when cloning, so assigning a new ID or create unique class based on previous ID has been my thoughts. On your second question - I've tried so many (unsatisfying) variations that I thought it being fruitless providing those examples.

Comment: Right, but the point of SO is to help you solve problems, you haven't really presented a problem. The way your question is worded currently, you want us to do the work for you.

Comment: Essentially what you'll need to do is connect the two sortables into one, then listen for the drop event. If the element is being dropped on a list that isn't the list it currently is in, clone it and append it to the new list if it isn't already there, and prevent the drop from happening so that the original stays in the original list.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I completely agree with what you're saying. Have updated the jsfiddle now.

Comment: jsfiddle went down for me, but i was able to copy the code before i lost it. This gets closer, but still has issues, i marked where the issues are. http://pastebin.com/T0ZawLvt